# Component doesn't show the validation/error message just an icon

Tags: validation, primefaces

I have an autocomplete with validator. If the validator fails, it doesn't show the error message. It is shown only in a tooltip.

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-3">                                  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{labels['product_console_ins_management_company']}"
                                        for="managementCompany" />
                                    <p:panel rendered="#{empty saveProduct.initShowId}" >
                                    <div class="form-control">
                                        <p:autoComplete id="managementCompany"
                                            required="true"
                                            requiredMessage="#{labels['product_console_ins_management_company_validation']}"
                                            value="#{saveProduct.product.company}"
                                            var="b" itemLabel="#{b.description}" itemValue="#{b}"
                                            completeMethod="#{saveProductConsoleController.completeInstrumentFactory}"
                                            process="@this" scrollHeight="300" forceSelection="true"
                                            converter="components.SimpleTypeBeanCollectionArrayConverter">
                                            <f:validator validatorId="managementCompanyValidator"/>
                                            <f:attribute name="boundList"
                                                value="#{domainData.instrumentFactoryList}" />                                              
                                        </p:autoComplete>
                                </div>
                                        </p:panel>
                                        <br />
                                    <p:outputLabel
                                        rendered="#{ not empty saveProduct.initShowId}"
                                        value="#{saveProduct.product.company.description}" />
                                    <p:message for="managementCompany" display="icon" />                                    
                            </div>
                        </h:panelGroup>
```

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9HIG.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **exactly** what *you* tell it to do and effectively your question is not related to the validator or the `p:autocomplete`.

From the [PrimeFaces documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/) (read it, use it, it IS usefull)

> **Display Mode**
>
> Message component has three different display modes;
>
> - text : Only message text is displayed.
> - icon : Only message severity is displayed and message text is visible as a tooltip.
> - both (default) : Both icon and text are displayed.

This can also be seen in the [PrimeFaces showcase for the message(s) component](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml)

So if you want different behaviour, choose a different value ('text' or 'both')